# Why does my windows computer keep getting this error whenever I try to extract a certain file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, extract, windows-error-reporting, error-logging

I'm trying to extract this file but whenever it extracts, it stops at 63% and presents this error to me every time.

I tried restarting my computer and re-downloading the file on several occasions but it doesn't seem to be helping.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to extract this file but whenever it extracts, it stops at 63% and presents this error to me every time.
>
> [image]

The error indicates the reason, the resulting path of the file, would exceed the limit imposed on files.

You will have to extract it to a different location.  By default Windows 10 has a 255 character path limit.

Even when Windows 10 only long paths optional feature is enabled, File Explorer, still has a 255 character limit.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused when you use Windows Explorer or WinZip to extract files and it encounters a file path that exceeds the maximum character limit.

To resolve this problem, use a decompression utility such as 7-Zip, that can handle long file paths. Otherwise, extract the files to the root directory or to the c:/temp directory.

Comment: No mention @ABAS HERSI Placing the zip file on the root level of the system drive is the safest way to avoid this problem.
*You can use long path tool*